# Как настроить вывод ошибок в браузер а не в лог ( nginx ) ?

Tags: php-nginx

Как настроить вывод ошибок  в браузер  а не в лог (  nginx ) ?

Answer (score 1):

В файле конфигурации (вероятно `php-fpm.conf`) укажите:

```
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_flag[display_startup_errors] = on
```

Comment: на хостинге доступен только nginx editor. При добавлении этих строк выдает ошибку

Comment: вы бы написали, что за ошибка. можно, например, попробовать php_admin_flag вместо php_flag.

Comment: В обоих вариантах :Ошибки в строках.:
    php_flag[display_errors] = on
    php_flag[display_startup_errors] = on